# Omit duplicates when merging dataframes with None in one column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Let's suppose, there are two dataframes.
The first one:

| User number | User address | User phone number | User FB profile | User has a dog | User is human |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Test st | 456789 | None | True | False |
| Jane | Testing av. | 340643 | None | False | True |

And the second one:

| User number | User address | User phone number | User FB profile | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Test st | 456789 | None | 345 |
| Jane | Testing av. | 340643 | None | 346 |

I want to merge second dataframe into first to know which rows in the first one have IDS from the second one and which do not. I do it in the following way:

```
merged_table = first_dataframe.merge(second_dataframe, how='left')
```

As the result I get the following

| User number | User address | User phone number | User FB profile | User has a dog | User is human | ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Test st | 456789 | None | True | False | NaN |
| Jane | Testing av. | 340643 | None | False | True | NaN |

Basically, It is the first dataframe with ID column added, but there are no values in it.
It happens because of the User FB profile column has None both in first and second (I checked it with records where this column had values - either in the first, or in the second, I got expected result) and the data from the second dataframe was completely disregarded.

How can I get a merged table where IDs from the second dataframe will be present on the same rows from the first one in such a case?

Comment: What is `print (first_dataframe.dtypes)` and `print (second_dataframe.dtypes)` ?

Comment: @jezrael first one - all "object" (in original, not example), including column with 'None's, second - all "object", including column with 'None's, + ID int64

Comment: If use `merged_table = first_dataframe.fillna('missing').merge(second_dataframe.fillna('missing'), how='left')` working?

Comment: @jezrael No, the same.

Comment: @jezrael solved it. there was an earlier astype(), that converted None in one DataFrame to 'None'